# What does the "RW" logo mean in a DVD+R?

Tags: dvd

If you look at this product:

[image: Verbatim DVD+R]

you can clearly see that it is a DVD+R, i.e. once it is written, it cannot be erased/rewritten.

Then what does the "RW" logo (in the lower right corner) mean? I thought it stood for ReWritable, but experimenting with the medium shows that it is not.

Comment: i add this for information:DVD+R and DVD+RW

DVD+R and DVD+RW formats are supported by Philips, Sony, Hewlett-Packard, Dell, Ricoh, Yamaha and others.

DVD+R is a recordable DVD format similar to CD-R. A DVD+R can record data only once and then the data becomes permanent on the disc. The disc can not be recorded onto a second time.

DVD+RW is a re-recordable format similar to CD-RW. The data on a DVD+RW disc can be erased and recorded over numerous times without damaging the medium.

Note: DVDs that have been made using a +R/+RW device can be read by most commercial DVD-ROM players.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's the logo of the [DVD+RW alliance](http://www.dvdservices.org/), the developers of the [DVD+R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD+R) and [DVD+RW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD+RW) formats.

> #### [History of the Alliance](http://www.dvdservices.org/alliance/history.htm)
>
> The DVD+RW Alliance is a voluntary group of industry-leading personal computing manufacturers, optical storage and electronics manufacturers including Dell, Hewlett-Packard Company, MCC/Verbatim, Philips Electronics, Ricoh Company Ltd., Sony Corporation, Thomson multimedia and Yamaha Corporation. The group seeks to develop and promote a universally compatible, rewritable DVD format to enable true convergence between personal computing and consumer electronics products.

The logo distinguishes DVD+R/RW disks from [DVD-R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-R)/[DVD-RW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-RW) and [DVD-RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-RAM) disks, which are competing and incompatible formats.

Comment: This makes very much sense: in the image it is too small to be read, but under the "RW" logotype it says "DVD+R", which identifies the type of medium.

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, RW is the logo of DVD+RW Alliance (Dell, HP, SONY, to name a few well-known names) that developed the "DVD+R" format (known as the "Plus" format).

This is in contrast to the DVD Forum (Hitachi, Toshiba, and interestingly, also SONY, among a few more) which developed the "DVD-R" (known as the "Dash" format... they will be very mad if you call it the "Minus" format).