# My DVD+R (RW) is not erasable/rewritable

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, burning, media, disc

I just bought a Sony DVD+R but I don't know if it's either +R or +RW. I assume it is a DVD+RW since the mark *"RW"* is written at the bottom of the disc. Same for my built-in desktop burner, it has a *"RW"* mark and tiny *"DVD+R DL"* is written below the *"RW"* mark.

When I'm trying to erase the content of the DVD. I used several DVD erasers, including [Active@ DVD Eraser](http://www.ntfs.com/dvd_eraser.htm).  Although the software is different, the result is the same, this is the error message:

[image]

I'm not sure the DVD is really "ReWritable", because the DVD Burner I used to burn DVD said the disc status is "DVD+R". That's weird, because apparently my DVD discs are rewritable. (I'm wondering it is rewritable...)

Are the discs non-rewritable? If so, could you tell me what does the *"RW"* mark stand for? And also, the *"AccuCORE"* :) Though I'm actually wanting to know is it rewrite compatible.

Comment: [See this page](http://superuser.com/questions/458198/what-does-the-rw-logo-mean-in-a-dvdr)

Comment: "I just bought a Sony DVD+R" which means the disk can only be written to once.

Comment: The "RW" logo just means it's a DVD **+** R standard disk, rather than DVD **-** R.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 types of DVDs you can buy at the store, R and RW.  It says DVD+R, so that just means it's only a 1 time writable DVD.  You want one that says DVD+RW or DVD-RW (+ and - doesn't matter in this case).  The RW logo doesn't actually mean it's a rewritable DVD, just like the DL doesn't mean it's a dual layer either.

I hope that helps, but when you purchase DVDs to use, on the package it should either say DVD-/+R or DVD-/+RW, and the RW will be more expensive.

Edit: Removed reference to finalizing the DVD, since I was wrong on how that works.

Comment: Finalize will not "lock" the RW so it can't be written again. It will close the session so it cannot be extended *without* erasing it. You can always erase it and write it again.

Comment: I had the wrong idea on that feature then, thanks for clearing that up.